# Akka.Net Invoke an Action inside an Actor class from a non-Actor class

Tags: action, actor, akka.net

Title pretty much says it all. I want to invoke an Action in an Actor class from a non-Actor class that is not in the same folder as the Actor if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the actor model, you don't "invoke an action" on the actor. You can *ask* for something or *tell* it something.
To do that, you need the actor's address, in akka.net you need an `IActorRef`.

I'm not sure what you mean by "folder", I'll just enumerate the possible meanings and the answer to each :

1. Same physical folder

   - The physical location of the actor class and the physical location of the "calling class" are not related to the ability to send messages to an actor.
2. Same namespace folder

   - The namespace does not directly influence the ability to send a message to an actor. It may only be influenced by the *visibility* of the message class to send.
3. Same *address* folder

   - Again, the *address* folder does not influence the ability to send a message to the actor.

To be able to send a message to an actor you only need it's `IActorRef`, there are multiple ways to manage those references that I'm not going write here because it depends on your application architecture.

I will, however, mention that you can also use the `ActorSystem.ActorSelection` method to obtain the reference of an actor that's located at a certain *path*, but this is **not** recommended because it may easily be misused and can lead to some bad habits. It's usage should be considered an advanced feature.

Once you got your hand on the actor reference, you then can call the `Ask` method from your non-actor class if you expect some result (beware, the result will be wrapped in a Task that you'll have to manage to retrieve the result).
If you don't expect an answer (or if you don't care about the response), you can just call the `Tell` method.
You have to pass the message to send to the actor to both of these methods.

Finally, once the actor receives your message, your message will *eventually* be processed and the actor will then do whatever it was designed to do.

If you haven't done it yet, the [bootcamp](http://learnakka.net) is a good way to learn the basis of akka.net.